# Cloud Firestore how to find all documents with subcollection containing specific document ID?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I’m trying to implement a way to maintain consistency in Firestore, but I need a way to find all the positions where the duplicate data exist.  Is there a way in firestore to find all documents whose subcollection contains documents with specific document ID?  For example, for the following structure

```
Users(collections){
    1234(document){
        Name: 
        Friends(collection){
            5678(document) {
                Name: 
            }
            9012(document) {
                Name:
            }
    }
    5678(document){
        Name:
    }
}
```

What query would I use to find all user ID whose Friends list contains a document with document ID 5678?  For example when user 5678 decided to change his/her name?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. Back in May Collection Group queries were introduced which allow you to search all collections with the same name, but that limitation won't work for your use case here since your users are stored in `Users` and their friends are stored in `Friends`.

If Friends were renamed to match Users and the `id` were also stored in the document it would be possible with this type of query:

```
let friends = db.collectionGroup('users').where('id', '==', id);
friends.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Answer (score 0):

It could be done. However you would need to add friend's id as a field because you can't query multiple documents by ID without the field. So, you will have this structure:

```
Users(collections){
    1234(document){
        Name: 
        Friends(collection){
            5678(document) {
                userId: 5678,
                Name: 
            }
            9012(document) {
                userId: 9012,
                Name:
            }
    }
    5678(document){
        Name:
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```dart
db.collectionGroup("Friends")
    .where("userId", isEqualTo: 5678)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) {
  snapshot.docs.map((d) {
    // here is the user document
    return d.reference.parent.parent;
  });
});
```

And don't forget to enable composite index for Friends subcollection.

P.S. Despite being Google's product, Firestore is still a pain to use product.